# scope variable value change asyn

Tags: angularjs, controller

All,

Right now, I am learning AngularJS directive and for simple tryout purpose I wrote a small script which is:

```
<html ng-app="vp">
<head>
    <title>try container</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body ng-controller="dashboard">


<testscope info="info.name"></testscope>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.10/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module("vp", []);
        app.controller("dashboard",["$scope", function($scope){
            $scope.info = {
                name:"scope",
                value:"scopevalue"
            };
            $scope.$on("showcontrollerscope", function(){
                console.log("scope in controller:", $scope.info.name);
            });

            $scope.$watch("info", function(newn, oldn){
                console.log("after change", $scope.info.name);
            }, true);
        }]);


        app.directive("testscope", function(){
            return {
                restrict: "AE",
                scope:{
                    info: "="
                },
                controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
                    console.log($scope);
                    $scope.$emit("showcontrollerscope");
                    $scope.info = "changed scope";
                    $scope.$emit("showcontrollerscope");
                }
            };

        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

My question is why the $on **outputs are both scope rather than scope and changed scope?** like in $watch.

I originally think the $emit is asyn, but someone said it is sync
They are synchronous.

See also https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/yyH3FYAy5ZY/APANNMnolD8J

I found many people suggest not use $watch in controller, so how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: You do know you're changing $scope.info from an object to a string right?

Comment: @MikeRobinson Sorry Mike, I do not quite understand what your meaning. Could you talk a little more about this?

Comment: @MikeRobinson Cos I read this: http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/      it said "=" considers the attr as data model rather than text

Comment: In your directive, you're doing this: $scope.info = "changed scope"; Regardless of what it's read as, you're changing it to a string.

Comment: @MikeRobinson thanks Mike. I guess I may have a misunderstanding here, I think this $scope in directive controller is the same as scope in directive, so the $scope.info is binded to dashboard controller's $scope.info.name, so actually I did not change data type , it is still string